# How to select element with specific class in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

```
<section class="refinementsContainer">
  <div class="contentfilters">
    <div class="refinementContainer refinementmicro" data-dimension="micro"></div>
    <div class="refinementContainer refinementcolor" data-dimension="color"></div>
    <div class="rightContainer">
      <div class="refinementContainer sort"></div>
      <div class="refinementContainer refinementSeason"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have this code. I need to append one class at only one `div` into the `div` with class `contentfilters`. I develop this code but it doesn't work:

```
$buttonOpenFilter.on(clickEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this).parent();
  var classOpen = 'open';

  if ($this.hasClass(classOpen)) {
    $this.removeClass(classOpen).css('max-height', 30);
  } else {
    $this.siblings().removeClass(classOpen).css('max-height', 30);
    $this.addClass(classOpen).css('max-height', $this.find('ul').height() + 105);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.contentfilters')`

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  here you will find everything about selectors.